# can't load movie AS2

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-2

I can't loadMovie in AS2, in the movie I have a XML gallery in the gallery timeline works perfect, when I call the gallery from _root.gallery.loadMovie("gallery.swf"); doesn't work :(
Please help me!!

Answer (score 0):

If I unterstand correctly, you are trying to get an SWF file to load another SWF file, which then loads XML data?

Then you will probably have to check your file paths.  If you load the XML from a relative path, i.e. `"../gallery.xml"` or even `"gallery.xml"`, the Flash Player's path will be relative to the `_root` file, not the `gallery.swf`.

Try using absolute paths, or move the XML data to a folder relative to the `_root` file.

Answer (score 0):

Try `loadMovieNum("filename", level)` instead of `loadMovie`.

In your situation:

```
_root.gallery.loadMovieNum("gallery.swf",1);
```